# k-means in dynamic programming complexity?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, dynamic-programming, k-means

We all know that the k-means algorithm:[image] which has a complexity of **O( n * K * I * d ) Where:**

1. n = number of points
2. K = number of clusters
3. I = number of iterations
4. d = number of attributes

but my question is when applying K-means in **Dynamic Programming** I can't figure out the complexity of it.

the idea of K-means using **DP** in a nutshell is as follows:

- Compute the proximity matrix
- Let each data point be a cluster
- **Repeat**

  - Merge the two closest clusters
  - Update the proximity matrix
- **Until** only a single cluster remains

I have tried to find a pseudo-code for it so I can try to find out the complexity, but I couldn't.

So, how can I find it's complexity? and what it could be?

Thank you guys in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you're describing is not k-means with dynamic programming, but rather a type of hierarchical clustering called [agglomerative clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering).  Typically, agglomerative clustering implementations take time (IIRC) O(n<sup>3</sup>d), where n is the number of data points and d is the number of features.  Wikipedia goes into a bit more depth about how this works.

Note that the clusters found this way are *not* the same as the clusters you'd get with k-means.  Agglomerative clustering tends to produce very different clusters with a different set of properties.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. anyway, still not clear. why **o(n3d)** and why not mentioning the number of iteration in the complexity measurement. Besides, yes this is a hierarchical clustering based approach. but still you can apply k-means on it. am I wrong??

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan- The number of iterations isn't a variable parameter in this version of clustering - it just finds clusters until all of the clusters have been merged together.  This contrasts with k-means, which can run for a variable number of iterations before converging.  As a result, there is no direct dependence on some parameter I for the number of iterations.  Does that make sense?

Comment: actually. I'm still in some kind of lack here!! but that does make sense. so there's no way to do k-means in DP??